# Want to Remove all the Characters Except First character in the word

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to c#, i need to trim a sentence which has many words. I need only first characters in all the words. For example

If a sentence is like this.

input : `Bharat Electrical Limited`  => output : `BEL` 
how do i accomplish this in c#?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and C#, what did you try?

Comment: split on spaces, take first of each result

Comment: Em try to trim the string it is not happening

Comment: @NaveenkumarR try my simple approach in the answer below.

Comment: Sorry for being irrelevant, but I just want to point out that this question should be awarded for having the most answers within an hour for the day. :D

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
string sentence = "Bharat Electrical Limited";
var result = sentence.Split(' ').Aggregate("", (current, word) => current + word.Substring(0, 1));
```

EDIT: Here's a brief explanantion:

`sentence.Split(' ')` splits the string into elements based on space (' ')

`.Aggregate("", (current, word) => current + word.Substring(0, 1));` is a linq expression to iterate through every word retrieve above perform an operation on it and

`word.Substring(0, 1)` returns the first letter of every word

Comment: You should explain what you do. Even if it is briefly.

Comment: @NaveenkumarR - You can mark it as answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Why aggregate function is giving error like System.Array does not contain a definition for Aggregate or missing directives?

Comment: It is working fine with console application, if i try the same thing in wpf it is not working and giving error ...

Comment: Ensure you're `using System.Linq;` and have a reference added to it.

Answer (score 3):

This is the sort of thing that's easily accomplished with a regular expression:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\S)\S*\s*", "$1");
```

This effectively matches consecutive non-white space characters, followed by white space, and replaces the whole sequence by its first character.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you want to [Split](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split) the string into words, then take First letter from each word. You can do this by a simple for loop like the following:

```
string inputStr = "Bharat Electrical Limited";
List<char> firstChars = new List<char>();
foreach (string word in inputStr.Split(new char[]{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    firstChars.Add(word[0]); // Collecting first chars of each word
}
string outputStr = String.Join("", firstChars);
```

And this will be the Short way for this:

```
string inputStr = "Bharat Electrical Limited";
string shortWord = String.Join("", inputStr.Split(new char[]{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x[0]));
```

If the first character in each string is not Caps, then you can use any of the following options.

1. Make the input into Title cased sentence, before performing the action.

For this you can use the following code:

```
inputStr = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(inputStr.ToLower());
```

2. Convert the Character to uppercase while we collect Characters from the word,

This can be achieved by:

```
firstChars.Add(char.ToUpper(word[0])); // For the first case
.Select(x => char.ToUpper(x[0])) // For the second case
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CIprpx) you can find a working example for all above mentioned cases

Comment: You might use `String.Concat` instead of `String.Join`.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez : I think `String.Join` is better than `Concatenation`. since `relies on an internal StringBuilder to build the joined string`, isn't it? then why you are suggesting  `Concatenation`?

Comment: Also, instead of changing the whole string to title case which might be expensive, why not simply `.Select(x => x[0].ToUpper())`?

Comment: See [String.Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784338(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: @Jcl : Nice idea, but `Char` doesn't have `.ToUpper()` method, If we want to do that means we need to do like this : `x[0].ToString().ToUpper()`

Comment: @un-lucky sorry, `char.ToUpper(x[0]);` should do ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d723h14(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: @Jcl : Sounds Great. I have included that in the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this -

```
string sentence = "Bharat Electrical Limited";

//Split the words
var letters = sentence.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

//Take firsst letter of every word
var myAbbWord = letters.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, letter) => current + letter.First());
```

`myAbbWord` should display *BEL* for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

I hope it helps.

```
string str1 = "Bharat Electrical Limited";
var resultList = str1.Split(' ');
string result = resultList.Aggregate(String.Empty, (current, word) => current + word.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is :

```
string inputStr = "Bharat Electrical Limited";

string result = new String(inputStr.Split(' ').Select(word => (word[0])).ToArray());
// BEL
```

You need to add `using System.Linq;` to your source file.

Logic is:

**Split** the string into array or words (delimited by space), then **project** this array by selecting the first char of each string. The result is an array of the first characters. Then using the **String overload constructor** taking char array, construct the result string.

Answer (score 0):

This might looks more friendly to you

```
string intput = "Bharat Electrical Limited";
string output = string.Join( "",intput.Split(new string[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Select(a => a.First()));
```

First split your input sentense with space and then use `First()` extension on `string` to get first character of string

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
  string inputStr = "Bharat Electrical Limited";
  var arrayString = string.Join("", inputStr.Split(' ').Select(x => x[0]));
```