# How can I concatenate two columns' data whilst only taking the first character of each entry to create an acronym in the new column?

Tags: r, concatenation

I have a data frame which has two columns that I need to concatenate:

```
Site       Location
site one   location one
site one   location two
site two   location one
site two   location two
```

I would like to create a new column that concatenates only the first character of each `Site` and `Location` value:

```
Site       Location       Concat
site one   location one   solo
site one   location two   solt
site two   location one   stlo
site two   location two   stlt
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex we can keep only first character of every word and paste them together.

```
transform(df, Concat = paste0(gsub('(\\S)\\S*\\s*', '\\1', Site), 
                              gsub('(\\S)\\S*\\s*', '\\1', Location)))

#      Site     Location Concat
#1 site one location one   solo
#2 site one location two   solt
#3 site two location one   stlo
#4 site two location two   stlt
```

Regex has been taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38259157/3962914).

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Site = c("site one", "site one", "site two", "site two"
), Location = c("location one", "location two", "location one", 
"location two")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  unite(Concat, Site, Location, remove = FALSE, sep=" ") %>%
  mutate(Concat = str_replace_all(Concat, "(^| )([a-z])[^ ]+", "\\2"))
#   Concat     Site     Location
#1   solo site one location one
#2   solt site one location two
#3   stlo site two location one
#4   stlt site two location two
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Site = c("site one", "site one", "site two", "site two"
), Location = c("location one", "location two", "location one", 
 "location two")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is an approach which uses the `abbreviate()` function:

```
df$Concat <- abbreviate(paste(df$Site, df$Location))
df
```

> ```
>       Site     Location Concat
> 1 site one location one   solo
> 2 site one location two   solt
> 3 site two location one   stlo
> 4 site two location two   stlt
> ```

According to `help("abbreviate")`,

> If an element of `names.arg` contains more than one word (words are
> separated by spaces) then at least one letter from each word will be
> retained.

Also note that the default value for the `minlength` parameter is 4.