# Concatenate first character substring from many columns into a new column without explicitly listing every column name

Tags: r, concatenation, across

### Problem Statement

I have a dataset which has 100 diagnosis fields, stored as character.  They are named `DiagnosisCode1` through to `DiagnosisCode100`.  In most cases, the first diagnosis field is complete, but not always.  Higher diagnosis fields are almost universally empty as `NA`.  I need to strip the first character off each of these fields and concatenate them in a single column which will be named `OnsetFlags`.  Because of the large number of columns I will be referring to, I would prefer not to explicitly reference all 100 fields, but refer to it either using a `dplyr` helper - such as `starts_with()` - or by using a range, like `DiagnosisCode1:DiagnosisCode100`.

### Example Data

For the purposes of a concise demonstration, the below dataset uses 5 diagnosis columns:

```
example = structure(list(id = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7"), DiagnosisCode1 = c("2G56.2", 
"2M48.06", "2G56.2", "2G56.0", "2S83.53", "2M23.20", "2S83.53"
), DiagnosisCode2 = c("2G56.0", "2G55.3", "2G56.0", "2G56.2", 
"2Y92.82", "2Z86.43", "2S83.2"), DiagnosisCode3 = c("2Z86.43", 
"2Z86.43", "2Z86.43", "1J98.1", "2V93.8", NA, "2W19"), DiagnosisCode4 = c(NA, 
"2U82.3", NA, "2U80.2", "2U73.8", NA, "2Y92.39"), DiagnosisCode5 = c(NA, 
"2U83.3", NA, NA, NA, NA, "2U56.39")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which produces:

```
  id DiagnosisCode1 DiagnosisCode2 DiagnosisCode3 DiagnosisCode4 DiagnosisCode5
1  1         2G56.2         2G56.0        2Z86.43           <NA>           <NA>
2  2        2M48.06         2G55.3        2Z86.43         2U82.3         2U83.3
3  3         2G56.2         2G56.0        2Z86.43           <NA>           <NA>
4  4         2G56.0         2G56.2         1J98.1         2U80.2           <NA>
5  5        2S83.53        2Y92.82         2V93.8         2U73.8           <NA>
6  6        2M23.20        2Z86.43           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>
7  7        2S83.53         2S83.2           2W19        2Y92.39        2U56.39
```

### Required Outcome

```
  id DiagnosisCode1 DiagnosisCode2 DiagnosisCode3 DiagnosisCode4 DiagnosisCode5 OnsetFlags
1  1          G56.2          G56.0         Z86.43           <NA>           <NA>        222
2  2         M48.06          G55.3         Z86.43          U82.3          U83.3      22222
3  3          G56.2          G56.0         Z86.43           <NA>           <NA>        222
4  4          G56.0          G56.2          J98.1          U80.2           <NA>       2212
5  5         S83.53         Y92.82          V93.8          U73.8           <NA>        222
6  6         M23.20         Z86.43           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>         22
7  7         S83.53          S83.2            W19         Y92.39         U56.39      22222
```

### Attempts

So far, I have tried my usual bag of tricks with `dplyr` `across()`:

```
  # create onset flag array
  example = example %>% 
    mutate(OnsetFlags = across(starts_with("DiagnosisCode"), ~ as.character(substr(., 1, 1))
      ))
```

However, this creates a tibble column which itself contains multiple OnsetFlags columns equal to the number of DiagnosisCode columns.  I'm having difficulty pulling these out of the tibble and concatenating into a dataframe column and, honestly, it feels like it's adding a lot of overhead for what I thought should be a simple process.

The closest other examples I've found on SO were:

[How can I concatenate two columns' data whilst only taking the first character of each entry to create an acronym in the new column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66257729/how-can-i-concatenate-two-columns-data-whilst-only-taking-the-first-character-o)

...but I don't seem to be able to `unite` the tibble columns.

Is there an easier way of doing this because I don't feel like I'm on the right path?

Comment: The 'tidy' approach would be - don't. Instead, `pivot_longer` this into a long, 'tidy' diagnosis dataset with `id/diagnosis_sequence/diagnosis` as variables. Then it's just a single `substr` to extract the condition onset flag. If you need to add diagnosis related details back to the main data then summarise your diagnosis set and `left_join` it on at the appropriate measurement level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this absolutely must be done in the wide format, I'd avoid `apply` (which loops over each and every row and will bog down on large datasets), and nest to deal with the `substr`/`unite` processing in the standard vectorised R fashion. Something like this should work, though it could probably be improved.

```
example %>% 
    mutate(onset = example %>% 
                       select(starts_with("DiagnosisCode")) %>%
                       map_df(substr,1,1) %>%
                       unite("onset", na.rm=TRUE, sep="")
                       %>% pull(onset)
    )
```

The 'tidy' approach however would be to not work with wide 'untidy' data. Instead, `pivot_longer` this into a long, 'tidy' diagnosis dataset.
Any summary information from your long diagnosis dataset can be joined on at the appropriate measurement level. This allows processing/analysis of grouped diagnoses and onset flags to be done in a very simple manner that doesn't get bogged down in variable prefix selections, apply/across logic, or needing to handle `NA` values because of the unbalanced number of diagnoses per event (note `values_drop_NA=TRUE` when pivoting).

```
diagnosis <- example %>%
    pivot_longer(-id,
                 names_pattern=".+(\\d+)",
                 names_to="seq",
                 values_to="code",
                 values_drop_na=TRUE) %>%
    mutate(onset = as.integer(substr(code, 1, 1)),
           code  = substr(code, 2, nchar(code)))

diagnosis
## A tibble: 26 × 4
#   id    seq   code   onset
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>  <int>
# 1 1     1     G56.2      2
# 2 1     2     G56.0      2
# 3 1     3     Z86.43     2
# 4 2     1     M48.06     2
# 5 2     2     G55.3      2
# 6 2     3     Z86.43     2
# 7 2     4     U82.3      2
# 8 2     5     U83.3      2
# 9 3     1     G56.2      2
#10 3     2     G56.0      2
## … with 16 more rows
```

Your current analysis task becomes a lot simpler:

```
diagnosis %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(onset = paste(onset,collapse=""))

## A tibble: 7 × 2
#  id    onset
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 1     222
#2 2     22222
#3 3     222
#4 4     2212
#5 5     2222
#6 6     22
#7 7     22222
```

Though I'd argue that combining *n* onset values violates most good practices for organising data where each cell should contain only one value, making future analysis more difficult as you'd have to then `strsplit` the values to make any sense of them. Better to leave it in the long format and analyse them as they are.

Here's another example of how to deal with other more complicated analyses in the long form:

```
diagnosis %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(onset1 = any(onset == 1),
              G5and2 = any(substr(code,1,2) == 'G5' & onset == 2))

## A tibble: 7 × 3
#  id    onset1 G5and2
#  <chr> <lgl>  <lgl>
#1 1     FALSE  TRUE
#2 2     FALSE  TRUE
#3 3     FALSE  TRUE
#4 4     TRUE   TRUE
#5 5     FALSE  FALSE
#6 6     FALSE  FALSE
#7 7     FALSE  FALSE
```

Comment: Yep, fair enough - running `apply()` over multiple years of data did bog things down.  Unpivoting was the approach I was originally using in SQL but the performance was underwhelming and fiddly.  The `pivot_longer()` approach in R is pretty quick and - as you say - provides easier opportunity for more complicated detection of invalid codes (and also performing comorbidity analysis).  I chose to remove the `names_pattern()` pivot option on my full dataset and apply `parse_number()` to the resulting `seq` column.  Boosted to answer.  Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

You could do with `substring()`, `substr()`, and `apply()`

```
example |> 
  mutate(
    across(starts_with("Diagnosis"), ~substring(.x,2)),
    onsetFlag = apply(select(example, starts_with("Diagnosis")), 1, FUN = \(x) na.omit(substr(x, 1,1)) |> paste(collapse = "")))
```

**output**

```
  id DiagnosisCode1 DiagnosisCode2 DiagnosisCode3 DiagnosisCode4 DiagnosisCode5 onsetFlag
1  1          G56.2          G56.0         Z86.43           <NA>           <NA>       222
2  2         M48.06          G55.3         Z86.43          U82.3          U83.3     22222
3  3          G56.2          G56.0         Z86.43           <NA>           <NA>       222
4  4          G56.0          G56.2          J98.1          U80.2           <NA>      2212
5  5         S83.53         Y92.82          V93.8          U73.8           <NA>      2222
6  6         M23.20         Z86.43           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>        22
7  7         S83.53          S83.2            W19         Y92.39         U56.39     22222
```

Comment: Impressive and tested as working on the full dataset.  I need to get better at understanding `apply` and where to use it.  Marked as answer.  Many thanks.